# List of popular importable calendar formats?

Tags: file, import, calendar, standards

Say I wanted to write a program that would export calendar data so that it could be imported into another calendar application.  What would be some popular formats for that, and where could I find information on the formats of those files?

Comment: By data you mean appointments and meetings?

Comment: @Hamish Yeah I guess that's accurate...anything with a Start Time/Date an End Time/Date and a description of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popular usage:
[Google summer of code](http://socghop.appspot.com/document/show/gsoc_program/google/gsoc2010/faqs#timeline) have three different format options:

> **Important Dates**
>
> You can also check out our Google Calendar in several formats:
>
> - XML
> - ICAL
> - HTML

where html is not really an export format as such. I would start with looking into the ical and the xml format they use.

Answer (score 2):

[.ics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) is a simple plain text (easily parsed / generated) calendar format supported by [several](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_applications_with_iCalendar_support) applications.